How to configure Android Studio to create new module gradle build scripts with convention plugins and not standard plugins
My current android projects all employ version catalogue, build-logic and convention plugins.
this all works fine...
until i add new sub modules with android studio
for all the new modules created, android studio adds the android library, jetbrains kotlin android, junit, etc.. plugins to both my libs.versions.toml file and the associated module build scripts.
in addition, although i have migrated my entire application to kotlin 2.0.0, by adding a new module android studio also adds a new version entry into my version catalogue of kotlinVersion = "1.9.0"
is there any way i can disable this android studio behaviour.
better still is there anyway i can get android studio to create new module build scripts that reference my convention plugins and not make unwanted changes to my libs.versions.toml file?
this is the version of android studio i am using...
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 8192M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
  ide.experimental.ui=true


"is there any way i can disable this android studio behaviour" -- stop using the new-module wizard and create your new modules by some other means (manually, custom-written generator script, etc.). "is there anyway i can get android studio to create new module build scripts that reference my convention plugins and not make unwanted changes to my libs.versions.toml file?" -- stop using whatever wizard you are using and create the new items manually.

I thought the Android studio wizard templates had been deprecated?
